# Python Unordered Listwith nodes: __str__ method

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write an __str__method for my UnorderedList class that can allow the list to be printed out in a format like: [1,2,3,4,5].

But for some reason it is only printing out the first position of the list. eg. [1] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]

```
def __str__(self):

    result = "["
    node = self.head
    if node != None:
        result += str(node.data)
        node = node.next
        for i in range(self.num_elements - 1):
            result += ", " + str(node.data)
            node = node.next
    result += "]"
    return result
```

Here is the rest of my Node and UnorderedList class methods...

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,initdata):
    self.data = initdata
    self.next = None

def getData(self):
    return self.data

def getNext(self):
    return self.next

def setData(self,newdata):
    self.data = newdata

def setNext(self,newnext):
    self.next = newnext



class UnorderedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.head == None

def add(self,item):
    temp = Node(item)
    temp.setNext(self.head)
    self.head = temp

def size(self):
    current = self.head
    count = 0
    while current != None:
        count = count + 1
        current = current.getNext()
    return count

def search(self,item):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    while current != None and not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            current = current.getNext()
    return found

def remove(self,item):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()

    if previous == None:
        self.head = current.getNext()
    else:
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())

def __str__(self):

    result = "["
    node = self.head
    if node != None:
        result += str(node.data)
        node = node.next
        for i in range(0 - 1):
            result += ", " + str(node.data)
            node = node.next
    result += "]"
    return result
```

Any help would be awesome. Also I feel like there is a much easier way of writing the **str**.

Comment: Tangential to your question, but if your list knows what its first element is, and each element knows what the next element is, then it's not unordered.  I don't see what the purpose of your class is.

Comment: I thought it was just a linked list and not unordered. But it's an assignment where the class needs to be called "UnorderedList". I should maybe change the question title to LinkedList with nodes?

Comment: and also, I'm stupid

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `self.size()` instead of `self.num_elements`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping incorrectly (both in the top version using a never-set `self.num_elements` and in the bottom one forcing the loop to never happen, as `range(0 - 1)` AKA `range(-1)` is of course `[]`.  Probably better:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = "["
    node = self.head
    if node != None:
        result += str(node.data)
        node = node.next
        while node:
            result += ", " + str(node.data)
            node = node.next
    result += "]"
    return result
```

The difference is to loop `while node:` rather than somehow trying to divine or force the number of elements involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    result = "["
    node = self.head
    while node:
        result += ('' if result == '[' else ", ") + str(node.data)
        node = node.next
    result += "]"

    return result
```